# Libgdx actor position resets after adding another action

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm making some simple animation using Actors (Labels, to be precize) and Actions.
My initial plan was to move one of them far to the left instantly, then make it smoothly appear through the edge of screen, replacing another. But every time a new Action is executed, Label's position resets, so I can't get the effect I planned. How do I avoid it? 
Here's code, if you need it:

```
    newAttack.addAction(Actions.moveBy(-1 * game.W, 0));
    newAttack.setText(game.local.get(_attack));
    newAttackType.background = game.skin.getDrawable("attack_" + getAttackType(_attack));
    lastAttack.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.moveBy(game.W, 0, 1.5f),
            Actions.run(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(lastAttack.getX() + " " + lastAttack.getY());
                newAttack.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.moveBy(game.W, 0, 1.5f), Actions.run(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                        lastAttack.addAction(Actions.moveBy(-1 * game.W, 0));
                        newAttack.addAction(Actions.moveBy(-1 * game.W, 0));
                        System.out.println(lastAttack.getX() + " " + lastAttack.getY() + "\n" + "--");
                        lastAttack.setText(game.local.get(_attack));
                        lastAttackType.background = game.skin.getDrawable("attack_" + getAttackType(_attack));
                    }
            })));
        }
    })));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not work, but looking into the source code of `Label.setText()` reveals that the method calls `Actor.invalidateHierarchy`. This means that whatever is containing the `lastAttack` actor will reset the `lastAttack`'s position.

So since you are adding the actions *before* you are calling `Label.setText()`, the position will be reset and then the actions won't work properly.

You should try setting the text, then setting the position of the actor to off screen, and then adding the slide in Action.